# How to use crypto hardware wallet to sign CSR (without the private key leaving the hardware)

Tags: cryptography, pki, cryptocurrency

Any hardware crypto wallet supports signing a transaction without the private key leaving the hardware, so theoretically it should be possible to sign a CSR as well. Is this true? If so, how can I do that?

PS I am also wondering if this is a good way to store the private key of a root CA offline, and maybe also splitting the private key into a couple of hardware wallets, say any 2 of 3 keys can recover the private key.

Comment: It is too broad of a question for stackoverflow. But for a real CA, that would depend entirely on the security of the particular hardware wallet. I don't think any of them are designed to the standard a real Internet CA would require. And splitting the key only makes sense if the wallet supports splitting and recombining. Otherwise you'd have to write software to do it which removes the private key from the card, which is entirely what you're trying to avoid by having hardware.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk Can you please point me in the right direction to further research on the topic? I cannot find good material discussing this to the level I would like to learn. Maybe I am missing some key terms or concepts? Thanks.